# Casting to custom type, Enumerable.Cast<T> and the as keyword

Tags: c#, linq, casting, ienumerable, explicit-conversion

This is more a question out of curiosity than necessity and came about having had to deal with Active Directory (MS) types such as `SearchResultCollection` (in the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace).

Frequently when dealing with AD in code, I find that I'm having to check values for null, Count, [0] .. whatever and convert what I get out .. all the while hoping that the underlying AD object via COM doesn't go poof etc.

After having a play about with `Parallel.ForEach` recently - and having to pass in an `IEnumerable<T>`, I thought, maybe it would be fun to see how I could cast a `SearchResultCollection` to an `IEnumerable` of my own custom type. In this type I would pull out all the values from the `SearchResult` object and stick them in my own, .NET managed code. Then I'd do away with the `DirectoryEntry`, `DirectorySearcher` etc. etc.

So, having already worked out that it's a good idea to do searchResultCollection.Cast() in order to supply Parallel.ForEach with it's source, I added an explicit operator for casting to my own type (let's just call it '`Item`').

I tested this out within the `ParallelForEach`, `var myItem = (Item)currentSearchResult`.

Good times, my cast operator is called and it all works. I then thought, it would be nice to do something like `searchResultCollection.Cast<Item>()`. Sadly this didn't work, didn't hit any breakpoints in the cast operator.

I did some Googling and discovered a helpful post which Jon Skeet had answered:

[IEnumerable.Cast<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760804/ienumerable-cast)

The crux of it, use .Select(...) to force the explicit cast operation. OK, but, hmmm.

I went off and perhaps disassembled `System.Core` -> `System.Linq.Enumerable.Cast<TResult>`, I noticed that this 'cast' is actually doing an 'as' keyword conversion under the hood:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)
{
    IEnumerable<TResult> enumerable = source as IEnumerable<TResult>;
    if (enumerable != null)
    {
        return enumerable;
    }
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    return CastIterator<TResult>(source);
}
```

I read some more and found this:

[Implicit/Explicit conversion with respect to the "as" keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873944/implicit-explicit-conversion-with-respect-to-the-as-keyword)

The top answer here states that '`as`' doesn't invoke any conversion operators .. use a (cast). Semantically I find this a little weird, since the extension method is called cast.. Shouldn't it be casting? There will no doubt be a really good reason why this doesn't happen, anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it would have used the cast operator instead of `as` it *still* wouldn't be invoking user defined explicit operators, so it wouldn't matter.  The only difference would be the type of exception thrown.

Explicit operators aren't known at all by the runtime.  According to the CLR there is no way to cast your search result to `Item`.  When the *compiler* notices that there is a cast that matches a given explicit operator it injects *at compile time* a call to that explicit operator (which is basically a static method) into the code.  Once you get to runtime there is no remaining knowledge of the cast, there is simply a method call in place to handle the conversion.

Because this is how explicit operators are implemented, rather than providing knowledge to the runtime of how to do the conversion, there is no way for `Cast` to inject the explicit operator's call into the code.  It's already been compiled.  When it was compiled there was no knowledge of any explicit operator to inject, so none was injected.

Answer (score 1):

> Semantically I find this a little weird, since the extension method is called cast.. Shouldn't it be casting?

It's casting *each element* if it needs to, within `CastIterator`... although using a generic cast, which won't use explicit conversion operator you've defined anyway. You should think of the explicit conversion operator as a custom method with syntactic sugar over the top, and not something the CLR cares about in most cases.

For for the `as` operator: that's *just* used to say "If this is already a sequence of the right type, we can just return." It's used on the sequence *as a whole*, not each element.

This can actually cause problems in some slightly bizarre situations where the C# conversion and the CLR conversions aren't aligned, although I can't remember the example I first came upon immediately.

See the [`Cast/OfType` post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/13/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-33-cast-and-oftype.aspx) within Edulinq for more details.

Answer (score 1):

It is casting. See the implementation of `CastIterator`.

```
static IEnumerable<TResult> CastIterator<TResult>(IEnumerable source) {
    foreach (object obj in source) yield return (TResult)obj; 
}
```

The use of the `as` keyword here is only to check if the entire collection can be casted to your target instead of casting item by item. If the `as` returns something that isn't null, then the entire collection is returned and we skip the whole iteration process to cast every item.

For example this trivial example would return a casted collection instead of iterating over every item

```
int?[] collection = ...;
var castedCollection = collection.Cast<int?>()
```

because the `as` works right off the bat, no need to iterate over every item.

In this example, the `as` gives a `null` result and we have to use the `CastIterator` to go over every object

```
int?[] collection = ...;
var castedCollection = collection.Cast<object>()
```

Comment: It's actually not just trivial conversions that are covered by casting the whole `IEnumerable`, due to covariance.  Any type of upcast will be handled by the `as`.  It's only downcasts (or sequences of value types, which don't support covariance) that can't be.

Comment: @Servy Yeah indeed! I meant that my example was trivial, not that only  trivial conversions are handled. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Apologies, I couldn't disassemble CastIterator for some reason Reflector isn't happy about showing me it in a readable form. So it does attempt to explicitly cast it, but the CLR doesn't know about my type so it barfs?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you need a [DynamicCast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18953867/2530848) which I wrote sometime ago.

Runtime doesn't know about implicit and explicit casting; it is the job of the compiler to do that. but using `Enumerable.Cast<>` you can't get that because `Enumerable.Cast` involves casting from `System.Object` to `Item` where there is no conversion available(you have conversion from X to Item, and not `Object` to `Item`)

Take the advantage of dynamic in .Net4.0

```
public static class DynamicEnumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> DynamicCast<T>(this IEnumerable source)
    {
        foreach (dynamic current in source)
        {
            yield return (T)(current);
        }
    }
}
```

Use it as

```
var result = collection.DynamicCast<Item>();
```

Comment: You can simply use `Select` as is described in the OP, to get the desired behavior without needing to re-compile the entire method at runtime for each object in the sequence.  Using `Select` adds just a few extra characters to the method call for somewhat stronger typing and dramatic performance improvements.

Comment: @Servy I agree that would need something like this `collection.Select(x=> (Item)(SearchResult))` but this answer should help ppl who really don't know what is the runtime type of the class which implements explicit cast.