# User-defined conversion for generic type

Tags: c#

I have an explicit conversion defined for a generic class in the following format:

```
class Generic<T>
{
    public static explicit operator NonGeneric(Generic<T> input) => //implementation
}
```

However, when I try to use the cast like:

```
void Fail()
{
    Generic<object> gen;
    NonGeneric nGen = gen as NonGeneric; //Cannot convert 'Generic<object>' to 'NonGeneric' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion etc
}
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what error are you gettng?

Comment: Use an explicit cast `(NonGeneric)gen`. The `as` operator is based on the type hierarchy

Comment: Added error text

Comment: Your conversion is explicit, and `as` does not invoke conversion operators.  Instead, use a direct cast.  See: [Implicit/Explicit conversion with respect to the “as” keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3874053). Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fd7fBk